# Velodyne has the same IP domain as my WIFI network

Tags: ros, wifi, ros-melodic, vlp-16, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Can I use WiFi and velodyne simultaneously? I thought the answer is yes if two network has different ip domain. Velodyne is 192.168.1.xx, while one of my network is 192.168.3.xx. It works well.

But when two domains are the same. Both are 192.168.1.xx. I can't use network any more. Is there any ways to address this? I can't modify my network subnet. If have to change the IP of velodyne, is it possible and how to do?

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391557/velodyne-has-the-same-ip-domain-as-my-wifi-network/) by [houhao](https://answers.ros.org/users/66924/houhao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2021-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The velodyne lidar provides a web browser page that you can use to change the device's IP address. It is found on port 80 of the velodyne's IP address.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [houhao](https://answers.ros.org/users/66924/houhao/) on 2021-11-28**:
Cool. Thanks a lot. I changed the ip before but forgot power cycle. It works now.